# Databricks REST API call for updating branch error : User Settings > Git Integration to set up an Azure DevOps personal access token

Tags: azure-devops, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-repos, databricks-rest-api

I am getting below error for updating the repo to a different branch using databricks rest api as mentioned at https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/repos.html#operation/update-repo .

I have authenticated using service principal and generated dbrks_bearer_token and dbrks_management_token.

Please find below code for same :-

```
import requests
import os
import json

TOKEN_REQ_BODY = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id':  'client_id',
    'client_secret':  'client_secret'
}
TOKEN_BASE_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' +  'tenant_id' + '/oauth2/token'
TOKEN_REQ_HEADERS = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}


def dbrks_management_token():
    TOKEN_REQ_BODY['resource'] = 'https://management.core.windows.net/'
    response = requests.get(TOKEN_BASE_URL, headers=TOKEN_REQ_HEADERS, data=TOKEN_REQ_BODY)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(response.status_code)
        return response.json()['access_token']
    else:
        raise Exception(response.text)
        return response.json()['access_token']

def dbrks_bearer_token():
    TOKEN_REQ_BODY['resource'] = '2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d'
    response = requests.get(TOKEN_BASE_URL, headers=TOKEN_REQ_HEADERS, data=TOKEN_REQ_BODY)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(response.status_code)
    else:
        raise Exception(response.text)
    return response.json()['access_token']

DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN = dbrks_bearer_token()
DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN = dbrks_management_token()


DBRKS_REQ_HEADERS = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN,
    'X-Databricks-Azure-Workspace-Resource-Id':
        '/subscriptions/susbcriptionid' +
        '/resourceGroups/rg-dev/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/dbr-dev',
    'X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token':  DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN }

DBRKS_CLUSTER_ID = {'cluster_id': 'cluster_id'}

def update_repo():
    DBRKS_START_ENDPOINT = 'api/2.0/repos/0328767704612345'
    postjson = """{
     "branch": "main"
  }"""

    response = requests.patch("https://adb-1234582271731234.0.azuredatabricks.net/"
                              + DBRKS_START_ENDPOINT,
                              headers=DBRKS_REQ_HEADERS,
                              json=json.loads(postjson))
    print(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(response.text)

    os.environ["DBRKS_CLUSTER_ID"] = response.json()["cluster_id"]
    print(response.content)

update_repo()
```

I am getting below error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/IdeaProjects/DBCluster/DB_rest_api.py", line 109, in <module>
    update_repo()
  File "C:/Users/IdeaProjects/DBCluster/DB_rest_api.py", line 104, in update_repo
    raise Exception(response.text)
Exception: {"error_code":"PERMISSION_DENIED","message":"Missing Git provider credentials. Go to User Settings > Git Integration to add your personal access token."}
403
```

Can someone please let me know if i need to anything explicitly at azure devops git configuration level as well?

Many thanks..!!

Answer (score 1):

To do any operations with Databricks Repos, you need to set a Git personal access token. Because you're using service principal, you can't set that personal access token via UI, but you can perform setting of that Git token using recently implemented [Git Credentials REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/gitcredentials) - just do that once for your service principal (or when Git PAT expires), and then Repos operations will work.

Comment: I am still confused how to do it using Git Credentials REST API but I have done it manually using PAT and DB Token. Is it possible for you to share any links/blog where it has been done using SPN??

Many Thanks..!!

Comment: it's done similarly to what you do in your code - generate bearer & management tokens and call corresponding Git Credentials API

Comment: Just commenting to add that I have succesfully used git-credentials API to add the bearer token generated with the msal library, but trying to use the Repos API afterwards results in the same error message as in OP.

Comment: For DevOps you need real PAT, not AAD token

Comment: How can I get a real PAT for a service principal/app registration? Is that a premium feature or can I somehow use a PAT generated for a user?

Comment: it's explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72256036/azure-databricks-api-cannot-add-repos-using-service-principal-and-api-calls/72273439#72273439